# how to mount beyond /dev/sda15 when using a GPT disk with lots of partitions

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, mount, gpt

I have a GPT disk with about 20 partitions.

They're on /dev/sda

how can I mount each of these at the same time?   as I understand /dev/sda is limited at /dev/sda15

this feels weird - being able to create something that cannot be mounted?  am I missing something?

Comment: linux imposes limits on the total number of any type of partition on a drive, so this effectively limits the number of logical partitions. This is at most 15 partitions total on an SCSI disk and 63 total on an IDE disk.

Answer (score 2):

That is due to Linux's SATA support being based on its SCSI hard disk subsystem. SCSI devices are limited to 15 partitions per device. See [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devices.txt) description from Linux Kernel sources:

```
8 block SCSI disk devices (0-15)
          0 = /dev/sda      First SCSI disk whole disk
         16 = /dev/sdb      Second SCSI disk whole disk
         32 = /dev/sdc      Third SCSI disk whole disk
            ...
        240 = /dev/sdp      Sixteenth SCSI disk whole disk

        Partitions are handled in the same way as for IDE
        disks (see major number 3) except that the limit on
        partitions is 15.
```

[This](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/HW212/com.ibm.storage.smric.help.doc/f2c_linuxdevnaming_2hsag8.html) article mentions something about this being a SCSI convention:

> Names without a trailing digit refer to the whole disk, while names
>   with a trailing digit refer to a partition of that whole disk. By
>   convention, SCSI disks have a maximum of 16 minor numbers mapped to a
>   single disk. Thus, for each whole disk, there is a maximum of 15
>   partitions per disk because one minor number is used to describe the
>   entire disk (for example /dev/sda), and the other 15 minor numbers are
>   used to refer to partitions for that disk (for example /dev/sda1,
>   /dev/sda2, etc). The following example displays the device files for
>   the whole disk /dev/sda, which has a major number of 8 and a minor
>   number of 0, and its 15 partitions.

There are lots of articles discussing this on the Web if you need more in-depth answer to the *why* part of your question.

There are at least two possible workarounds to this limitation.

### Offset Mounting

This is achieved by adding an `offset=` option to the `mount` command. The value needed for the option can be obtained by multiplying the sector size and starting byte of the partition you are mounting. Both of these values are available in the output of `fdisk -lu /dev/sdX`. Example:

```
fdisk -lu /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: [..]
[..]
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
[..]

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
[..]
/dev/sda18      232421376   254679039    11128832   83  Linux
/dev/sda19      200783872   232419327    15817728   83  Linux

# Mount /dev/sda18 to /media/somedir1
mount -o rw,offset=$((512*232421376)),defaults /dev/sda /media/somedir1

# Mount /dev/sda19 to /media/somedir2
mount -o rw,offset=$((512*200783872)),defaults /dev/sda /media/somedir2
```

Notice that I put `/dev/sda` instead of `/dev/sda18` and `/dev/sda19`.

### Use LVM

Another option is to use LVM. However, this may entail some file shuffling and therefore may be time consuming. Most importantly, LVM volumes can be hard to access from other operating systems, such as OS X before Lion and Windows, so it might not be suitable for your needs. There are many posts about LVM here and in other places, so I am not getting into how to set it up here.

Comment: Actually, SCSI (or IDE/ATA) has nothing to do with partitions. SCSI doesn't handle partitions, just disk devices. Depending on the SCSI version, the limit is either 8 or 16 devices per bus, one of which is the SCSI host adapter -- but that's whole-disk devices (`/dev/sda`, `dev/sdb`, and so on). Partitions are defined at a higher level (in the OS; or in the case of EFI, in the computer's firmware); to SCSI, partitions are just data patterns sent over the bus. The fact that the Linux kernel has limits on the number of partitions in the SCSI code is a kernel issue, not a SCSI issue.

Comment: @Rod Smith: citation needed.

Comment: See [here](http://ask.adaptec.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1971/~/how-many-scsi-devices-can-be-attached-on-a-scsi-controller%3F) for SCSI limits. As to partitions, see [the Wikipedia article on partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning) and note that no mention is made of SCSI, ATA, or IDE (except in the title of one reference). Also note that there are several partition table types (MBR, GPT, BSD, etc.). To behave as you suggest, SCSI would need to understand them all -- even data structures newer than SCSI itself. SCSI is a lower-level protocol than partitions.

Comment: @Rod Smith, both credible sources I cited in my answer specifically mentioned 'partition', not 'disk'.

Comment: Your sources both refer to *Linux* conventions for handling SCSI, not *SCSI limitations* per se. The two are *very* different. At the level of SCSI, a disk is a source of raw, uninterpreted data. Partitions lie on a level well above that. FWIW, I'm the author of the GPT fdisk partitioning tools, so I understand this pretty well.

Comment: @RodSmith, Yes, that's what I wrote in my answer, *convention*. The *limitation* part refers to the particular Linux kernel the OP was using. Stop wasting my time.

Answer (score 1):

What distribution are you using? The limit you describe was present in very old kernels, but most distributions have long since worked around it via udev configurations or other means -- quite honestly, I don't recall the details of how. I just checked, and my Ubuntu 14.04 installation can handle a USB flash drive with 20 GPT partitions with no trouble:

```
$ ls -l /dev/sdd*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk   8, 48 Jul 23 19:16 /dev/sdd
brw-rw---- 1 root disk   8, 49 Jul 23 19:16 /dev/sdd1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk   8, 58 Jul 23 19:16 /dev/sdd10
brw-rw---- 1 root disk   8, 59 Jul 23 19:16 /dev/sdd11
brw-rw---- 1 root disk   8, 60 Jul 23 19:16 /dev/sdd12
brw-rw---- 1 root disk   8, 61 Jul 23 19:16 /dev/sdd13
brw-rw---- 1 root disk   8, 62 Jul 23 19:16 /dev/sdd14
brw-rw---- 1 root disk   8, 63 Jul 23 19:16 /dev/sdd15
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 259,  0 Jul 23 19:16 /dev/sdd16
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 259,  1 Jul 23 19:16 /dev/sdd17
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 259,  2 Jul 23 19:16 /dev/sdd18
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 259,  3 Jul 23 19:16 /dev/sdd19
brw-rw---- 1 root disk   8, 50 Jul 23 19:16 /dev/sdd2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 259,  4 Jul 23 19:16 /dev/sdd20
brw-rw---- 1 root disk   8, 51 Jul 23 19:16 /dev/sdd3
brw-rw---- 1 root disk   8, 52 Jul 23 19:16 /dev/sdd4
brw-rw---- 1 root disk   8, 53 Jul 23 19:16 /dev/sdd5
brw-rw---- 1 root disk   8, 54 Jul 23 19:16 /dev/sdd6
brw-rw---- 1 root disk   8, 55 Jul 23 19:16 /dev/sdd7
brw-rw---- 1 root disk   8, 56 Jul 23 19:16 /dev/sdd8
brw-rw---- 1 root disk   8, 57 Jul 23 19:16 /dev/sdd9
```

Fedora 20 also handles it just fine, although with different device numbers. Both OSes permit me to access the 20th partition. (I didn't try accessing every partition, just the highest-numbered one as a proof of concept.)

Thus, if you're having problems with this, I recommend you ask on a distribution-specific forum, or at least post the name of the distribution you're using. Adjusting your kernel and/or udev configuration might help, but I'm afraid I don't recall the details of how this issue was overcome -- as I say, the fix has been "in" for so long that I've forgotten how to do it manually.